# Dropdown selection change to update database in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to populate list of model in a view using table. where one field is a dropdown list.

When dropdown selection is changed, the value of the selected and the model id (or whole model with updated dropdown value) has to be passed to the controller which updates the database.

With the help of a few links I tried using jQuery to transfer data (learning and new to ASP.NET MVC and jQuery)

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $("body").on("change", "#ddlFruits", function () {
            $("#hfFruitName").val($(this).find("option:selected").text() + ":" + document.getElementById("hfFruitName").value);
            document.forms["Form1"].submit();
        });
        </script>
```

is a jQuery

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "Initiative", FormMethod.Post, new { @name = "Form1" }))
{
    @Html.DropDownList("Fruits", new SelectListItem[]{
                            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Good work", Value="Good work"},
                            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Wow", Value="Wow"},
                            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Keep it up", Value="Keep it up"}}, "Select a Remark", new { @id = "ddlFruits" })
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.Id,  new { @id = "hfFruitName"})
    }
```

it is showing dropdown but what ever dropdown we select it is updating only
the first row or data.

If I select the dropdown of 10th row value of 10th row and id or 1st row is passed

sample link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q3BCOhTPRkllIiq4NnW9Gd1kgtySqJTo/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This question seems to have been translated, and might not have clearly stated the problem. Please rewrite this question to clearly convey your intentions.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q3BCOhTPRkllIiq4NnW9Gd1kgtySqJTo/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Above is the sample I Tried. check the output in submit action where formcollection recieves the selected row drop down text and value as 1;

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a guess but I reckon your line

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.Id,  new { @id = "hfFruitName"})
```

is the problem.

Try changing it to

```
<input type="hidden" id="hfFruitName" name="id" value="@item.Id">
```

Comment: Dave,it is not working, i have shared a sample app for IYW please help with solution